# How to use join in sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am using Microsoft SQL server, and I want to use the `join` but from multiple tables.

This is what I have

```
select a.*, b.Position_Name, c.StartDate, c.EndDate--, e.firmName
from NewHire a--, Firms e
join Position b on a.Position_ID = b.Position_ID
join WorkPeriod c on a.HireID = c.HireID-- and c.FirmID = e.FirmID
where a.Archived = 0 
order by a.HireID desc
```

I want to have the c.FirmID match the e.FirmID, however I get the error

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.Position_ID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.HireID" could not be bound.
```

I have commented out the three parts in the first code block, which causes the error. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

**EDIT: actually nevermind, I don't need help with this question.**

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are mixing JOIN types, trying using the same JOIN throughout:

```
select a.*, b.Position_Name, c.StartDate, c.EndDate, e.firmName
from NewHire a
join Position b 
    on a.Position_ID = b.Position_ID
join WorkPeriod c 
    on a.HireID = c.HireID
join Firms e
    on c.FirmID = e.FirmID
where a.Archived = 0 
order by a.HireID desc
```