# Getting The multi-part identifier error in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL query, I am getting the error:

> The multi-part identifier "a.Position_ID" could not be bound.

I'm not sure whats causing it. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

```
select distinct 
   a.HireLastName, a.HireFirstName, a.HireID, a.Position_ID, a.BarNumber, 
   a.Archived, a.DateArchived, b.Position_Name
from NewHire a, WorkPeriod c
join Position b on a.Position_ID = b.Position_ID
where 
    a.Archived = 0 
    and a.HireID = c.HireID 
    and c.InquiryID is not null 
order by 
    a.HireID DESC, a.HireLastName, a.HireFirstName
```

Comment: Are you sure `Position_ID` exists in `NewHire`?

Comment: The order of joins are not necessarily implemented in the order you write them. This is particularly problematic when you mix bad, old-style, implicit joins with proper, explicit joins. Try using a JOIN instead of a comma between a and b, and moving the a = c condition to that on clause.

Comment: @imthepitts that's not the problem. The problem is `a` doesn't exist when the join between `b` and `c` is attempted. Otherwise it would say `invalid column`.

Comment: `Position_ID` does exist, and all a.Position_ID values exist in the Position table.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: Can you show me what you mean, I am not sure how to write that?

Comment: Seriously? `FROM NewHire a JOIN WorkPeriod c ON a.HireID = c.HireID`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use join in sql query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526487/how-to-use-join-in-sql-query)

Comment: But if your joining table c, c doesn't have the coloumn name Position_Name, b has it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not join table c, which I think can cause issues with your alias a.  Can you try this:

```
select distinct 
    a.HireLastName, 
    a.HireFirstName, 
    a.HireID, 
    a.Position_ID, 
    a.BarNumber, 
    a.Archived, 
    a.DateArchived, 
    b.Position_Name
from NewHire a 
join Position b on a.Position_ID = b.Position_ID
join WorkPeriod c on a.hireID = c.HireID
where a.Archived = 0 and c.InquiryID is not null 
order by a.HireID DESC, a.HireLastName, a.HireFirstName
```